# How to return a error message in R?

Tags: r

I was wondering how one is able to produce error messages in R, especially from within a function?

Comment: It's not exactly an answer (that's why I make it a comment here) to @petermeissner question, but surely often overlooked and helpful in this context: `geterrmessage()` returns the last error message, enabling you to pass error messages from other functions (used within your own functions) around. Quite helpful when used with `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Since you don't specify what you really want, all I just can say is take a look at

```
?message # prints a message but not stop execution
?warning # prints a warning message but not stop execution
?stop # stops execution of the current expression and executes an error action.
```

Answer (score 51):

Simply include `stop()` inside your function/script

If you'd like an error message, include it inside `stop()` like so

```
stop("This is an error message")
```