# Catching (HTTP) Exception and throw again in R

Tags: r

I am trying to catch and then again throw a exception in R. So that the client can read the exception and handle it.

I have tried these links, but none of them works

[Equivalent of "throw" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608130/equivalent-of-throw-in-r)

[How to return a error message in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723800/how-to-return-a-error-message-in-r)

To be exact I need to rewrite this program in R.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class test {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException  {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://google.com");
            InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            System.out.println(is);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried

```
library(bitops)
library(RCurl)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(methods)
library(getPass)
library(OData)
library(xml2)
library(curl)
status <- function() {
  data = tryCatch({
    url = "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(cscsmmmc110sj01dvwgyolkm))/TripPinServiceRW/People('rufssellwhyte')/Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.GetFavoriteAirline"
    print(retrieveData(url))
  }, error = function(error_message) {
    print("HI")
    print(error_message)
    return (NA)
  }, finally = {

  })
}
```

And this is the correct url

"http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(cscsmmmc110sj01dvwgyolkm))/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.GetFavoriteAirline"

I need to print HI and the error msg if any there is any error and throw the error.

Comment: you're after [`tryCatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/5977215), ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the example @ rndus2r,@ SymbolixAU

Comment: you use `stop()` to generate fatal errors (i.e. "exceptions")

Comment: Can you send me some code samples, I didn't get you actually I am new to r.